# JS scripts folder other than "scripts" not visible after deployment on server ASP .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

Could you please tell me if there is a place in configuration files where I should mark that my scripts are not only in "script" folder but also in "js" folder? After deploy on IIS I cannot see js folder, but I can see "Content" "fonts" and "scripts".
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on how you are deploying your scripts. Are you bundling them? What does your bundle config look like? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you deploy, but I assume that you use Web Deploy from Visual Studio.

In that case, make sure that when you right-click the files in Solution Explorer and choose Properties, the Build Action is set to `Content`.